# Displaying module constants or values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I define an angular.module with some constants or values, what is the simplest way to display them in the view?

For instance, given

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
  .constant('APPLES', 4)
```

How can I display the value of `APPLES`? I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
<html ng-app="MyApp">
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    <p>There are {{ APPLES }} apples.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

But that doesn't work.

---

The simplest way I've gotten it to work (which is quite complicated, and not scalable if there are many such constants) is this:

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
  .constant('APPLES', 4)
  .directive('numApples', ['APPLES', function(apples){
    return function(scope, elm, attrs) {
      elm.text(apples);
    };}])
```

And use the view:

```
<html ng-app="MyApp">
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    <p>There are <span num-apples></span> apples.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've created a demo [here[image: screeny]](http://plnkr.co/edit/yjsAJPE9PqjdGqMK7mVm?p=preview).

Comment: Well, the simplest I know is to inject them into controller

Comment: A good non-academic example is if I want to add an application version, last modified date, etc to some headers and footers around the site.

Comment: constant has to be injected to be used. Either in directive, service or controller

Comment: @Alain that's not really an example of constant. In my book, constant is something that doesn't change with time. App version, last modified date do.